# deleting record from DB if it doesn't match the scraped data

Tags: php, laravel

I have little problem about deleting data from DB. I do some scraping. And saving datas into DB. I scrape same website for update several times. And the data scraped before. Not exist in the website anymore. Then I want to delete that data's id from DB too.

```
foreach($planNames as $k => $names)
{
    $database = [];
    $database = [
        "plan_id" => $insertedPlaceId,
        "plan_name" => $names,
        "plan_price" => $planPrice[$k],
        "people" => $people[$k]
    ];

    if ($plan = Plan::where("plan_name", "=", $names)->first()) {
        if ($plan->plan_name != $database["plan_name"]) {
            $plan->id->delete();
            $this->line("Plan deleted.");
        }
    } else {
        Plan::insertGetId($database);
        $this->line("Plans inserted.");
    }
}
```

I think this part is not quite working `$plan->id->delete();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$plan->id->delete()` is not the correct way, you can use one of the below:

To delete a model, call the delete method on a model instance:

```
$plan = App\Plan::find(1);

$plan->delete();
```

Deleting an existing model by Key

```
App\Plan::destroy(1);           -- Using id
App\Plan::destroy(1, 2, 3);     -- Using comma separated string
App\Plan::destroy([1, 2, 3]);   -- Using array
```

Delete models by query

```
$deletedRows = App\Plan::where('active', 0)->delete();
```

Reference: [Laravel - Deleting Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models)

If you are using SoftDelete then refer to [Laravel - Soft Delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: @mr.hello, if it does solve your problem, don't forget to upvote it :)